# Swift "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift

I have this error only in the main app , in the app that I make the code it's working perfect, but not in main. 
Thanks

```
@IBAction func sliderMoved(slider:UISlider) {
   currentValue = lroundf(slider.value) 
}

func startNewRound() {
    targetValue = 1 + Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    currentValue = 50
    slider.value = Float(currentValue)  //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value   
}
```

Comment: Well, if you read the error... it's because an optional unwrapped and it's nil... probably your slider is nil at the time startNewRound is called.

Comment: Most popular Swift question ever: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"! And the answer is basically the same every time. Over 1000 on SO, Google reports: About 38,600 results.

Comment: @zaph yeah, it's pretty heart breaking to see the lack of error these 'programmers' put into debugging things....

Comment: Sorry , i have only 3 months of programming in back , and i asked because in one ViewController all code it's work perfect , but in single one it's not working . I guess you knew everything from first. And i read the error , i am not an idiot . I solved , i forgot to connect a func to the slider , and yes i don't now english perfect , because i am from a little country in Europe , Romania , and i am only 17 years old and i am not a genius, and next time please , remember from you have started , with i guess a University , with 3-4 years , not 3 months of programming , and 0 experience before.

Comment: @ChiojdoiuAndrei never assume people's history and never assume you don't have the same starting point as someone else. One aspect of programming you must learn immediately is problem solving. Reading issues and diagnosing them. This is a simple thing that doesn't require years or even months of programming experience to diagnose, and I will warn you that you will have a hard time picking this up if you don't read the error message and learn how to deduct this type of issue using the process of elimination. There are definitely reasonable issues to ask via a post, but this isn't one of them...

Comment: Mind you, people are always available to help, but you should go through a book first or watch some tutorial videos and experiment with stuff to learn how it works. That will give you a basic understanding of error messages and how everything is connected/functions.

Comment: @TheCodingArt i know , i am still learn from a book , i know the error means , but the problem was because in a ViewController work's in another not, i solved the problem , a connection of the slider wasn't made good , i don't know why.. Excuse me , i was a jerk..

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're calling startNewRound() before the slider is actually initialised e.g before viewDidLoad() of the view it is in is called. To fix this issue, make sure that you are waiting until the view is initialised and all outlets are not nil.

Comment: A function wasn't connected good to the slider , i don't know why or how , but thank's :D